# I have a error with my code

Tags: java, android

It keeps saying that the constructor is undefined. I already read somewhere that I need to declare the constructor with no arguments. I just don't know how to do that.

If someone could help, I'm new at java and programming. My code is below

```
package com.alextrost.onscreenjoystickdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameSurface1 extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 

private Context _context1;     
private GameThread1 _thread1;
private GameControls1 _controls1;
private GameJoystick1 _joystick1;

private Bitmap _pointer; 

public GameSurface1(Context context) {
    super(context);    
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    _context1 = context; 
    init1();      
}

private void init1(){

    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback( this);



    //  A call will be made to start it later
    _thread1 = new GameThread1(holder, _context1, new Handler(),this);
    setFocusable(true);


    _joystick1 = new GameJoystick1(getContext().getResources());


    _pointer = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

    //controls
    _controls1 = new GameControls1();
    setOnTouchListener(_controls1);



}


public void doDraw1(Canvas canvas){

    //update the pointer
    _controls1.update(null);

    //draw the pointer
    canvas.drawBitmap(_pointer, _controls1._pointerPosition1.x, _controls1._pointerPosition1.y, null);

    //draw the joystick background
    canvas.drawBitmap(_joystick1.get_joystickBg(), 50,220, null);  

    //draw the dragable joystick
    canvas.drawBitmap(_joystick1.get_joystick(),_controls1._touchingPoint1.x -357, _controls1._touchingPoint1.y -26, null);

}



//these methods are overridden from the SurfaceView super class. They are automatically called 
//when a SurfaceView is created, resumed or suspended.
@Override 
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
private boolean retry1;
@Override 
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    retry1 = true;
    //code to end gameloop
    _thread1.state1 = GameThread.STOPED;
    while (retry1) {
        try {
            //code to kill Thread
            _thread1.join();
            retry1 = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}

@Override 
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    if(_thread1.state1==GameThread1.PAUSED){
        //When game is opened again in the Android OS
        _thread1 = new GameThread1(getHolder(), _context1, new Handler(),this);
        _thread1.start();
    }else{
        //creating the game Thread for the first time
        _thread1.start();
    }
}

public void Update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Please, always add the error message in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor is a method with the same name as your class (`GameSurface1`) and no return values so this is a constructor:-

```
public GameSurface1(Context context)
```

...and this is a constructor with no arguments:-

```
public GameSurface1()
```

Comment: Yes but `GameSurface1` extends `SurfaceView`, and `SurfaceView` doesn't have a no-arg constructor. So I suppose that adding a no-arg constructor won't solve his issue.

Comment: Then you can't create a no argument constructor, where does it tell you that you should

Comment: Yes, you answered the part _"I already read somewhere that I need to declare the constructor with no arguments. I just don't know how to do that."_. But the real problem here is _"It keeps saying that the constructor is undefined"_. We need the real error message of the OP.

Comment: I answered the only part of the question that is answerable at this point.  I'll extend my answer if more information becomes available.

Comment: yes, the real problem is "It keeps saying that the constructor is undefined". I'm sorry about that i make you guys confused T.T

Comment: and that error could happen at various locations throughout the code so we don't know where to look to solve that problem without seeing the error and being pointed to which line it is being reported at.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

**Default constructors**:

> If the programmer does not supply a constructor for an instantiable
>   class,  most languages will provide a default constructor. The
>   behavior of the default constructor is language dependent.  It may
>   initialize data members to zero or other same values, or it may do
>   nothing at all.  In C++ a default constructor is required if an array
>   of class objects is to be created.   Other languages (Java, C#, VB
>   .NET) have no such restriction.

**Example of Default Constructor**:

```
public GameSurface1();
```

**Parameterized constructors**:

> Constructors that can take arguments are termed as parameterized
>   constructors.   The number of arguments can be greater or equal to
>   one(1).When an object is declared in a parameterized constructor,
>   the initial values have to be passed as arguments to the constructor
>   function. The normal way of object declaration may not work.  The
>   constructors can be called explicitly or implicitly.  The method of
>   calling the constructor implicitly is also called the shorthand
>   method.

**Example of Parameterized Constructor**:

```
public GameSurface1(Context context);
```

Comment: Always quote your [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)).